# How do I get the date time when a record was last inserted into a database table?

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to display when a record was last inserted into a table in a MySql Database. I tried the query below but it seems to be displaying the wrong time.

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM information_schema.tables
where TABLE_SCHEMA='flightop_staff'
and TABLE_NAME="college";
```

Comment: 'seems to be displaying the wrong time.' - in what way is it worng? and have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think information schema hold this date.

Usually, we have an "inserted_at" (or whatever column name you choose) timestamp (or datetime) column declared within the table, then we could retrieve the most recent with the following query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(inserted_at) as last_inserted_date FROM my_table
```